# Shortcut to rename multiple files in the Finder

Tags: keyboard, finder, shortcut

In the Finder, it is possible to rename the selected file by pressing the "Enter" key.

When multiple files are selected, it is possible to batch rename them using some simple rules by right clicking on the files and then clicking "Rename X files...".

Is there a shortcut to rename the files which are selected, so that one does not need to move the mouse, right click, select the rename button, etc.?

Although one might expect that pressing enter when multiple files are selected would do this, pressing enter then does not seem to have this effect (it appears to do nothing).

Comment: You seems to have already answered this yourself; multiple selection, Enter does nothing, only right-click Rename...

Comment: You could rename them using the terminal and a do loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I don't need so many files renamed simultaneously I simply added this few shortcuts for different numbers

[image]

To do this open Preferences > Keyboard > App Shortcuts > <kbd>+</kbd> and add `Finder` with exact `Rename 2 Items...` menu title and so on)

[image]

There is [more complex solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8181322) via automator, which I don't like it as it resets `Rename Menu` state each time you open it.

Comment: Alternatively using BetterTouchTool you can use a wildcard to invoke the menu bar item! I didn't even realize that this was available in the menu bar, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, probably best way is to select files and right click. There will be an option to rename xx files, where xx is the number of files selected. I used this and it works great and fast.  It allows you to input a common part of the name that all the files will share and then you can have it add sequential numbers to distinguish the files.